# Embed other site in “safe” way

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed

I want to make an iframe and embed an external site without allowing or extremely limiting that page’s ability to affect the DOM and JavaScript context of the parent page. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you trying to prevent and how regular same-origin policy does not solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iframe can't access most of the properties of the parent iframe cross-origin because of [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

So there is very little it will be able to do, although it could redirect the parent document to another URL.

If you need to limit it further, there is the [`sandbox` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) which you can use to limit the access further.

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Use the [`sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) property of the [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe):

```
// Fully sandboxed
<iframe src="..." sandbox />

// Partially sandboxed, see docs for full set of options
<iframe src="..." sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups" />
```

Do note that older browsers (IE 10 for example) do not support this, and it may cause the iframe to break on those browsers.